# Nuance Power PDF Automation using Excel VBA Macro

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to automatically control Nuance Power PDF to merge PDF files and create table of contents and bookmarks using Excel VBA Macro.

I found some information on how to accomplish this task using Adobe's Acrobat, but I haven't found anything regarding Nuance Power PDF.

So my question is: which reference do I have to set in VBA and is there some sort of help file containing the common methods and objects to address Power PDF over VBA?

Answer (score 2):

The file which you seek is called "Power PDF 2 Automation interface.doc" by Bence.Balazs@nuance.com

Add the following reference 
PDFPlus
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nuance\Power PDF\bin\GPlusCore.dll

Here is example code from the file for insert a page into a pdf from another pdf.

```
Dim PDFApp As PDFPlus.App
Dim ddDocTarget As PDFPlus.ddDoc
Dim ddDocSource As PDFPlus.ddDoc

Set PDFApp = CreateObject("NuancePDF.App")
Set ddDocTarget = CreateObject("NuancePDF.DDDoc")

If ddDocTarget.Open("mydoc.pdf") = False Then
    PDFApp.Exit
    Exit Sub
End If

Set ddDocSource = CreateObject("NuancePDF.DDDoc")

If ddDocSource.Open("pdfpages.pdf") = False Then
    ddDocTarget.Close
    PDFApp.Exit
    Exit Sub
End If

If ddDocTarget.InsertPages(1, ddDocSource, 0, 2, False) = False Then
    ddDocSource.Close
    ddDocTarget.Close
    PDFApp.Exit
    Exit Sub
End If

If ddDocTarget.Save(DDSaveFull, " mydoc.pdf") = False Then
    'Saving the file failed
End If

ddDocSource.Close
ddDocTarget.Close
PDFApp.Exit
```

Comment: What version of PDFPlus works with this code? I have version 6, but I get an error at `Set PDFApp = CreateObject("NuancePDF.App")`. Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object.

Comment: @Aaron C I don't see anything wrong with your code so I'm thinking you probably do not have the library's referenced in your project.  It should work once you do that.  Also, ordinarily I sit on the early/late binding fence because they both have merits - but - in this case, I definitely recommend early binding to get the benefit of intellisense.  Unless you like the challenge.